# Number of photons required for communication

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantization, telescopes, noise

On one hand, the amount of information I can transmit is proportional to the bandwidth. The higher the frequency, the more information I can transmit. On the other hand, the number of photons is reverse proportional to the frequency. I cannot possibly transmit more information than the number of photons I send. Therefore, it appears, that at low intensity levels, a higher frequency signal may contain less information than a lower frequency signal.

For example, consider a camera sensor in a high amplification mode (known in digital photography as "high ISO"). Provided the light intensity is uniform by color, blue sensor pixels would receive fewer photons than red pixels. The photon noise in modern sensors is one of the main quality limitations. Thus, in low light conditions, blue images would be grainier than red images meaning that the amount of the transmitted information is reverse proportional to the frequency.

Considering these two competing trends, an optimum must exist. 
Is there a known formula or estimate for the optimal frequency to transmit the highest amount of information for a given received power? Or, stating this in reverse, is there a formula for the minimum received power required to avoid the photon quantization noise at a given frequency?

Comment: "I cannot transmit more information than the number of photons" - why not? Photons have multiple attributes that could be used to encode information, polarisation (H/V/C), frequency, detection time, and so on. In other scenarios 1bit of information requires many photons.
 I think the answer to this question depends on how information is encoded.

Comment: @JMLCarter Absolutely! However, the amount of information in such conditions would still be proportional to the number of photons, even if you count all their attributes. So I'm just interested if there indeed is an optimum or some other effects prohibit it. For example, low frequencies have many photons, but cannot transmit much information. So just the number of photons doesn't mean much alone.

Comment: One of the key ideas here is temperature. If the temperature of the detector is such that $kT > h f$ where $f$ is the photon frequency, then the detector won't work too well because it will be thermally excited.

Comment: Theoretically, you could have four times as many blue photon sensors on a plate than red photon sensors, because blue photons have half the wavelength. So if you're communicating by aiming photons at sensors, rather than trying to detect images with low levels of light, blue photons have compensating advantages.

Comment: @PeterShor Good point. I did think that the wavelength was a factor. For example, I can have an enormous number of photons at a low radio frequency, but detecting them would require tools of a large physical scale.

Comment: Your radio actually detects low frequency photons moderately well, and it's not a tool of huge physical scale. (Of course, in a noiseless environment it doesn't approach the theoretical limit on information capacity, but the main reason for that is because it doesn't reach the precision corresponding to quantum shot noise, and not because it doesn't detect photons one at a time.) If you had a shot-noise precision radio, a point radio source for transmission, and no noise but attenuation, the classical formula for capacity – $C = B \log_2 (1+S/N)$ – is essentially equal to the quantum formula.

Comment: As Peter Shor's answer makes clear, the concept of shot noise is central here, but your question suggests you might not be that familiar with the concept. If that's the case, make sure you understand it well.

Comment: Also, suggestion: remove the irrelevant tag 'telescopes'.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Hi Emilio, thanks for your comments! Much appreciated :) I am indeed well familiar with the shot noise both theoretically and also practically from my hobby of digital photography. So your comment rather suggests that you might not have understood my question the way I intended. My apologies, I should have phrased it better :) I didn't have the *telescopes* tag at first. It was suggested by JMLCarter above. I'm not an expert in astronomy, but I've heard that the Hubble collected the deep field image practically photon by photon, so the tag does not seem irrelevant. Thanks again!

Comment: @PeterShor Based on your "radio" comment I wonder if I've poorly phrased my question, cause its intent doesn't seem to be getting through to people. Let's see if this example works. I listen to a rock band on the radio. The audio range is 20kHz. There are 1000 radio stations in the range sharing the bandwidth. If we could transmit this information using a large number of low frequency photons in, say, the meter radio band, it would be a revolution in telecom. But it doesnt work this way, because the modulation (information, entropy, whatever) will push the radio bandwidth much higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optimal distribution of photon frequencies for sending messages, assuming no noise but quantum shot noise, is indistinguishable from thermal (blackbody) radiation at a given temperature. So find the temperature for thermal radiation corresponding to your desired power, find its entropy, convert that to bits, and you have the theoretical maximum amount of information for a given power.

Why is this true? I'll give a brief sketch of a proof. The Holevo formula for the quantum information that can be sent over a quantum channel ${\cal N}$ at a given power is

$$
\max_{\{ p_i, |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i | \}} S\left({\cal N}\left({\sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|}\right)\right) - \sum_i p_i S\left(\cal N( | \psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i | )\right), $$
where the maximization is over all probability distributions of input states to the channel with the desired power constraint, and $S$ is entropy. In words, this is the entropy of the average output less the average entropy of the output.

If the channel is noiseless, then the second term on the right-hand-side is 0, and you just need to maximize the entropy of the average channel output. This maximization is the same as the maximization for determining a thermal state of the channel output given a fixed power.

Of course when you try to do this, you may run into problems, like discovering that the spatial width of your channel (which you haven't specified) makes a difference.  I suspect that you would need to specify your problem quite a bit more before you could get a definite numerical answer.

If you're trying to send a signal through an environment with noise, the theorem that the optimal distribution of photon frequencies is a thermal state no longer holds, and things get much more complicated. But I think that for your question, you wanted the assumption of no noise.

Comment: Interesting, bu not clear to me. Can you please elaborate?  "indistinguishable from thermal radiation" - why?  "find the temperature ... corresponding to ... power" - how? The second part is understood - I'm not looking for a numeric answer, just a concept.

Comment: "Find the temperature ... corresponding to ... power". If you're sending the signal using electromagnetic radiation (say through a wave guide, which is just a long pipe), there are formulas for how much power is in a thermal state of electromagnetic radiation at a given temperature, and for how much entropy is in a thermal state at that temperature. Look these up and use them.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I see now what you mean. So there indeed is an optimal frequency (or frequency distribution) for given power in a given channel, as I expected. So, if I use a narrow frequency band (like radio stations do) instead of the wide spectrum of the black body, would you agree that the optimal frequency would match (at least approximately) the peak frequency of the black body spectrum?

Comment: If you use a narrow frequency band, then the classical information capacity is $C=B \log_2(1+S/N)$. For quantum noiseless channels at low frequencies, the quantum information capacity will be almost exactly the same, with the noise being quantum shot noise. If you reduce the frequency and keep the same power, the shot noise gets smaller, and the capacity approaches infinity as the frequency approaches $0.$

Comment: For intuition about why this happens ... the classical continuous noiseless channel has infinite capacity. (You put in a power level with an infinite number of digits, and you get exactly the same power level out.)  And as you make the frequency smaller while keeping the power fixed, the quantum channel behaves more and more like the classical continuous channel.

Comment: This seems to contradict your earlier statements. If the channel is fixed in physical width and the frequency decreases, the number of photons increases and we have to count them in series. But we cannot count faster than the frequency of the photons. Because, if we could, we would start a revolution in telecom and become millionaires. The lower the frequency of the line is, the higher data throughtput it would have. Great let's get rich!!! :)

Comment: If you keep the bandwidth fixed (which you seem to want to do), then the formula $C=B\log_2(1+S/N)$ shows you want to maximize the signal-to-noise ratio. If the only noise is shot noise – vacuum fluctuations – that's done by making the frequency as low as possible (the capacity doesn't actually go to infinity because of your constraint on power ... I was wrong above). Of course, this is unrealistic. But once you introduce realistic constraints, like detection technology and actual ambient noise, the answer is that it depends on ***lots*** of things that you haven't specified in your question.